# How to use .names with dplyr mutate across and an anonymous function

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Referring to the documentation for `across()` (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html), you can specify the name returned from the dplyr verb using the `.names` argument. Viz

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), mean, .names = "mean_{.col}"))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Species    mean_Sepal.Length mean_Sepal.Width
#>   <fct>                  <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 setosa                  5.01             3.43
#> 2 versicolor              5.94             2.77
#> 3 virginica               6.59             2.97
```

However, when I use a purr style anonymous function I receive an error:

```
iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>%
   mutate(across(contains(".Width"), ~.x - mean(.x), .names = "residual_{.col}"))

#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
#> x glue cannot interpolate functions into strings.
#> * object '.col' is a function.
#> i Input `..1` is `across(contains(".Width"), ~.x - mean(.x), .names = "residual_{.col}")`.
#> i The error occured in group 1: Species = "setosa".
#> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Removing the `.names` argument removes the error. How is one supposed to specify names using `across` in a dplyr verb with an anonymous function?

Comment: I tried both of your codes and get the error. Then I updated `dplyr` from v1.0.0 to 1.0.2 and both ran fine, without error.

Comment: Verified! Thanks Dan.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this problem can't be replicated using an up-to-date version of the tidyverse.

Answer (score 8):

Try removing the dot in `.col`, so it will be: `.names = "residual_{col}"`

Comment: The [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html#arguments) seems to indicate you do need the dot

Comment: I find it interesting that it works with _both_ `{.col}` (as defined) and `{col}`. Sounds like either a bug or undocumented tolerance.